# Using Bootstrap CSS Class how to increase card tile

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using form.IO, which only has a field for targeting controls with Bootstrap custom CSS Classes. No `syle` tags no .control{font-size:20px}

you can use multiple classes separated by a space
Ex:  `card-title mb-2 text-muted`

I want to set only the card Title to `h2`
If I try `h2`, this will set `all` text in the control to `h2`

I tried `h2 card-title` and `card-title h2` hoping to target just the card-title but this does not work

How to set card-title to h2 or increase font size using Bootstrap custom CSS Classes

Thanks

Comment: What about h2.card-title {  font-size:20px } added to your css file?  I think you are missing the . is all, so it knows which h2 class to use this style.  If that works I will type up a full answer.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly. I added `h2.card-title { font-size:20px }` to my CSS file and then tried `h2.card-title` in my `Custom CSS Classes` input. Alas no effect

Comment: You know i just re-read what you posted, you are saying it doesn't have to be h2 but were using that as a way to force the increase in side?  When you inspect the output what font-size does it display? You can always try to add !important to the end of the css command to force it to over ride something inhereted.  Another thing is if you do it in line on the element such as style='font-size:20px;'' does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work using this

```
.lb-md {
  font-size: 19px;
  .checkbox input[type="checkbox"], .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: relative;
  }
  .radio + .radio, .checkbox + .checkbox {
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  label {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .text-muted, .help-block {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .fa {
    font-size: 1.75rem !important;
  }
}
```